# parent local variable acting as shared variable between three child

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

How come in the below program the local variable of parent process is acting as a shared variable between three child processes.

```
int main()
{
    int turn = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            int me = i;
            while (turn != me)
                /*do nothing*/ ;

            // my turn
            printf("Process %d ran\n", me);
            turn++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Process 0 ran

Process 1 ran

Process 2 ran

But according to me the last two processes should hang as the value of turn should never change for them.

Also if i put a exit(0); after turn++, I am returned immediately to my shell prompt with only one line of output i.e:
Process 0 ran

But still the other two processes keep running in the background and no output by any of the other two processes.

Comment: What exactly makes you think `turn` gets shared?

Comment: as the initial value of turn = 0, when the for loop enters second time me = 1 and turn should be equal to 0 only as we have changed it in a child process not in parent so when second time entering the for loop
turn should be = 0 and me = 1
thus while(turn != me) ; //should run infinitely code should not come below this

Comment: How many processes do you expect your code will create?

Comment: it should be three...where i got it wrong please tell.

Comment: now i got it that 6 processes will be create as hitting a end of a loop is just a branch statement if we see in low level and thus forked processes will jump back to for loop creating those extra processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on:

```
main process is 0.

process 0 calls fork. i = 0;
process 0 returns from fork = 1;
process 0 calls fork. i = 1;
process 0 returns from fork = 2;
process 0 calls fork. i = 2;
process 0 returns from fork = 3;
process 0 exists;

process 1 returns from fork. i = 0;
process 1 hits the while loop turn = 0, i = 0, me = 0, while loop exists;
process 1 calls printf.
process 1 increments turn, turn = 1;
process 1 goes back to the for loop;
process 1 calls fork, i = 1;
process 1 returns from fork = 4;
process 1 calls fork, i = 2;
process 1 returns from fork = 5;
process 1 exists;

process 2 returns from fork. i = 1;
process 2 hits the while loop turn = 0, i = 1, me = 0, while loop spins forever;

process 3 returns from fork, i = 2;
process 3 hits the while loop turn = 0, i = 2, me = 0, while loop spins forever;

process 4 (spawned from process 1) returns from fork, i = 1, turn = 1 (inherited from process 1).
process 4 hits the while loop turn = 1, i = 1, me = 1, while loop exits;
process 4 calls printf;
process 4 increments turn, turn = 2;
process 4 goes back to the for loop;
process 4 calls fork, i = 2, turn = 2;
process 4 returns from fork = 6;
process 4 exits;

process 5 (spawned from process 1) return from fork, i = 2, turn = 1 (inherited from process 1)
process 5 hits the while loop turn = 1, i = 2, me = 2, while loop spins forever;

process 6 (spawned from process 4) returns from fork i = 2, turn = 2 (inherited from process 4)
process 6 hits the while loop turn = 2, i = 2, me = 2, while loop exists;
process 6 calls printf;
process 6 drops out of the for loop
process 6 exits;
```

Basically, you need to remember that all processes you will continue running the for loop, not just the main one. After that it's not too hard to figure out what's going on. You spawn 6 processes in total and three of them will have the right state of `i` and `turn`.

Comment: so if we do fork in a loop that forked process will also run that parent loop, if yes then whether loop will be started from the beginning or it will continue from its current value. i.e. initialization will be done again or not.

Comment: The child process will be in exactly (at least in this case) same state as the parent. The for loop will be in the exact same state as the parent. From the point of view of the operating system that performs the `fork` call, there is no for loop at all, there's just a bunch of values in registers and in memory and the registers and memory in the child are exactly the same as in the parent (at least in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Refactor your code like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int turn = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("forking i = %d, turn = %d\n", i, turn);

        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            int me = i;
            while (turn != me)
                /*do nothing*/ ;

            // my turn
            printf("Process %d ran\n", me);
            turn++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It may come as a shock to you but as Art's refactoring above shows pretty clearly your code will spawn 6 processes. Putting some more printfs in there should get your understand what's really going on.

Comment: really shocked.. i had never thought that forked process would also continue run the loop

Answer (score -2):

Variable declared before fork() is shared for child processes. You may check it by printing &turn in loop. It will be same.

Comment: It will be updated for all beacause they doesn't have the copy of "turn" they have shared access to "turn" you may check address of turn. By this command `code`printf("%u",&turn);`code` in loop.

Comment: they doesn't have shared access i am sure.

Comment: I tried printing address of "turn" in loop, it is same. Here is the code `code` #include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

int turn = 0;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
                int me = i;
                while (turn != me)
                        /*do nothing*/ ;

                // my turn
                printf("Process %d ran\n", me);
                printf("%u",&turn);
                turn++;
        }
}

return 0;
} `code`

Comment: This address is in a virtual address space not actual physical address.For example
If we have two boxes one named parent and one child.

Both the boxes contain numbers 1 to 10.

So in child box also we have say number 5,

and in parent box also we have number 5.

The number is same but in different boxes.

Similar in the above case the address is same, but in different process address spaces.